# Magento, Set stock_status_changed_auto

Tags: magento-1.9

What is the correct way to update stock_status_changed_auto

I am adding items into Magento 1.9 programmatically and all the fields are correct except for stock_status_changed_auto is 1 when it should be 0

I've tried both stock_status_changed_automatically and stock_status_changed_auto. The field in cataloginventory_stock_item is stock_status_changed_auto, but looking at the Magento response it sends stock_status_changed_automatically

My Code,

```
->setStockData(array(
        'use_config_manage_stock' => 1, //'Use config settings' checkbox
        'manage_stock' => 0, //manage stock
        'use_config_min_sale_qty' => 1, //Minimum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart
        'use_config_max_sale_qty' => 1, //Maximum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart
        'is_in_stock' => $final['is_in_stock'], //Stock Availability
        'qty' => $final['qty'], //qty
        'stock_status_changed_auto' => 0,
        'stock_status_changed_automatically' => 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

stock_status_changed_auto is a flag that indicates whether the stock has been automatically changed or not.

Have a look in `Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Stock_Item` and `Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Stock` to see the flag and variable being set/used